# FCFS with character invalid

Tags: c++, programming-challenge

Any suggestion to improve this, they ask me to input characters that should be an invalid input and ask you again to input the number of process without crashing the program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int bt[20],wt[20],avwt=0,i,j;
     int n;

     cout<<"Enter total number of processes(maximum 20):";
     cin>>n;
     while(char (n))
     {
          if(isalpha(n))
          {
                cout<<"Invalid Input";
          }


       cout<<"\nEnter Process Burst Time\n";
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
            cout<<"P["<<i+1<<"]:";
            cin>>bt[i];
       }

       wt[0]=0;    
       for(i=1;i<n;i++)
       {
             wt[i]=0+bt[i];
             for(j=0;j<i;j++)
             wt[i]+=bt[j];
       }

        cout<<"\nProcess\t\tBurst Time\tArrival Time";

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {

             avwt+=wt[i];
             cout<<"\nP["<<i+1<<"]"<<"\t\t"<<bt[i]<<"\t\t"<<wt[i];
        } 

        avwt/=i;

        cout<<"\n\nAverage Waiting Time:"<<avwt;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Can you include the link to the challenge, and copy and paste at least part of the problem description into the question?

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly what this code is supposed to accomplish, but there are at least a few comments I think are valid regardless.

#### Avoid `using namespace std;`

This brings an extremely large number of names into scope. While perfectly reasonable with other namespaces, you *usually* want to avoid it with the `std` namespace.

#### Your use of `isalpha`

This code:

```
 cout<<"Enter total number of processes(maximum 20):";
 cin>>n;
 while(char (n))
 {
      if(isalpha(n))
      {
            cout<<"Invalid Input";
      }
```

... makes very little (if any) sense to me. You've read a number from the user, then you're trying to use `isalpha` on that. Since (in C and C++) `char` is a small integer type, it's valid (from the compiler's viewpoint) to pass that `int` to `isalpha`, but it's really not meaningful at all.

Given that you want a number less than or equal to 20, it would probably be best to check for that before using it though--as it stands now, if the user enters something like 30, the code will blithely continue trying to run, and write past the ends of the arrays it has allocated.

#### Use of arrays

That brings us to the next obvious problem: you're probably a lot better of using something like `std::vector` (or possibly `std::array`) rather than the arrays that are built into the language. These behave much better in general: they know their own size, don't decay to points the minute you look at them wrong, and are generally just a whole lot better.

#### Treat users humanely

Demanding that a user enter 20 (or even 10) process burst times interactively is inhumane. It would be much better to (for example) accept a file containing the burst times instead.

#### Use applicable standard algorithms

First of all, it looks to me like your computation of arrival times:

```
   wt[0]=0;    
   for(i=1;i<n;i++)
   {
         wt[i]=0+bt[i];
         for(j=0;j<i;j++)
         wt[i]+=bt[j];
   }
```

...is actually broken. Since you're storing the first arrival time as 0, you have a total of one more arrival time than burst times.

I'd switch to using `std::vector`s as mentioned previously, and then use the standard `partial_sum` algorithm to do most of the work:

```
wt[0] = 0;

std::partial_sum(bt.begin(), bt.end(), std::back_inserter(wt));
```

I believe this produces the results you wanted: for N inputs, it produces 0 for the first result, and each succeeding result is the sum of the burst times up to that point.

#### Names

Many of the names you've used (e.g., `bt`, `wt`, `avwt`) are (I suppose) quick to type, but certainly hard to read. I'd prefer to see `burst_time`, `wait_time`, `average_wait`, so I could read them a little more easily.

#### Output

Since you have one more arrival time than burst time, you may want to report your results a little differently. Right now, at least as I read things you're not reporting (or actually even computing) the last arrival time. Since the sequence is really that process 0 starts at time 0, and each successive time is based on the previous process times, I think I'd arrange the columns with the arrival time on the left and the process time on the right, so the numbers read more meaningful from let to right, top to bottom (i.e., in the direction people normally read).

For formatting output into columns, I'd also advise using `std::setw` instead of tabs.

Putting those together, we might end up with code something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::ifstream in(argv[1]);

    // Read the burst times from the file into our vector:
    std::vector<int> burst_times{ std::istream_iterator<int>(in), {} };

    std::vector<int> arrival_times{ 0 };
    std::partial_sum(burst_times.begin(), burst_times.end(), 
                     std::back_inserter(arrival_times));

    int width = 10;
    std::cout << "\n" << std::setw(width) << "Process" 
                      << std::setw(width) << "Arrival" 
                      << std::setw(width) << "Duration" << "\n";

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < burst_times.size(); i++)
        std::cout << std::setw(width) << i + 1 
                  << std::setw(width) << arrival_times[i] 
                  << std::setw(width) << burst_times[i] << "\n";

    std::cout << std::setw(width) << i + 1 
              << std::setw(width) << arrival_times[i] << "\n";

    auto total_times = std::accumulate(arrival_times.begin(), arrival_times.end(), 0);
    auto average_time =  total_times / arrival_times.size();

    std::cout << "\n\nAverage Waiting Time: " << average_time << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The advice to use a standard algorithm and standard structure such as `std::vector` is particularly good.  I almost never use a plain array any more.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a number of things that may help you improve your program.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Use `<cctype>` instead of `<ctype.h>`

The difference between the two forms is that the former defines things within the `std::` namespace versus into the global namespace.  Language lawyers have lots of fun with this, but for daily use I'd recommend using `<cctype>`.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734230/math-interface-vs-cmath-in-c/8734292#8734292) for details.

### Use whitespace to improve readability

Lines like this:

```
for(j=0;j<i;j++)
```

become much easier to read with a little bit of whitespace:

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

Further, especially when you are beginning, it's useful to always put the curly braces there.  Doing so will make your intentions clear to both readers of the code and the compiler and can reduce the possibility for certain kinds of subtle bugs like this:

```
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            wt[i] += bt[j];
            std::cout << wt[i];
```

Without the braces, the indentation suggests that both lines should be within the loop, but in reality the compiler would only execute the `std::cout` line *after* the loop.  Your indenting has the opposite problem in that the two lines look like this:

```
for(j=0;j<i;j++)
wt[i]+=bt[j];
```

I'd strongly recommend writing that instead like this:

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    wt[i] += bt[j];
}
```

### Consider separating I/O from the algorithm

Right now, everything is done in main.  Better practice is to separate things into functions.  In particular, I'd recommend separating the input/output routines from the actual simulation.  That way the phases would be, essentially 1) input data and validate, 2) run the simulation 3) show the simulation results.

### Use longer, more meaningful names

Names like `n` and `bt` are not very descriptive. Because this is a fairly short program, this isn't a terrible flaw, but it's worth considering if there might be more meaningful names that could be used.

### Fix the bugs

The program only sets the value of `avwt` to zero at the beginning, so all subsequent average weight time calculations are invalid.  Also, the calculation of `wt[i]` for each process is incorrect and more complex than it needs to be.  A simple way to fix both problems is to replace the existing calculation code with this:

```
avwt = wt[0] = 0;
for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    wt[i] = wt[i-1] + bt[i-1];
}
```

### Omit `return 0`

When a C or C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no need to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

**Note:** when I make this suggestion, it's almost invariably followed by one of two kinds of comments:  "I didn't know that." or "That's bad advice!"  My rationale is that it's safe and useful to rely on compiler behavior explicitly supported by the standard.  For C, since C99; see ISO/IEC 9899:1999 section 5.1.2.2.3:

> [...] a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.

For C++, since the first standard in 1998; see ISO/IEC 14882:1998 section 3.6.1:

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

All versions of both standards since then (C99 and C++98) have maintained the same idea.  We rely on automatically generated member functions in C++, and few people write explicit `return;` statements at the end of a `void` function.  Reasons against omitting seem to boil down to ["it looks weird"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581993/what-the-reasons-for-against-returning-0-from-main-in-iso-c/2582015#2582015).  If, like me, you're curious about the rationale for the change to the C standard [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394171/what-was-the-rationale-for-making-return-0-at-the-end-of-main-optional).  Also note that in the early 1990s this was considered "sloppy practice" because it was undefined behavior (although widely supported) at the time.

So I advocate omitting it; others disagree (often vehemently!)  In any case, if you encounter code that omits it, you'll know that it's explicitly supported by the standard and you'll know what it means.

Comment: I didn't know you...um, wait...yeah I did. Well it is bad...no, wait. It's not a bad idea at all. Oh well, at least the obligation to comment on it has been met, so nobody else has to bother. :-)

Comment: @JerryCoffin YOU'RE WRONG!  Oh, no wait.. ;)